# how to insert a text value in input field of web page using htmlAgilityPack in c#?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack for web scraping in c#.
How can I insert a value into an input field on a web page and get the result.
for example : insert "C#" string to search field in google and get result.

Comment: First you have to figure out how google search queries work and create the appropriate query. Then you have to fetch the page for that query.

Comment: Tnx nakiya . If a page uses the POST method to send information, how I can  found a appropriate query?

Comment: @AlirezaRezaei What site are you trying to scrape? Some scraping tools work better than others. HtmlAgilityPack might not be your best choice.